# How to use radio buttons in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

please I need a help here as am learning how to use radio buttons in python. I have records of many years (2021, 2022, 2023) in a database called practice.db. I want when a user select a particular month from the Combobox and selected a particular year from the radio buttons, only the records of a selected month of a selected year to be displayed in the treeview.

**Here is my code**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now() # creating date object
year=today.year # Present Year as Integer

year1 = today.year+1 #Next Year
year2= today.year-1  #Previous Year

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")  # Size of the window
root.title("practice")  # Adding a title

my_path=r'E:\Sales-and-Inventory-Management-System-master\login.db'

r1_v = tk.IntVar(value=year) # declaring Intvar

my_conn = sqlite3.connect(my_path)

tracing = tk.StringVar()
my_dictionary = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03', 'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06', 'July': '07', 'Aug': '08',
           'Sep': '09', 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec': '12'}

def my_function(*args): # on click of radio buttons
    query1 = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE strftime('%Y',Date)='" +str(r1_v.get())+ "'"
    r_set1 = my_conn.execute(query1)
    saleslist = r_set1.fetchall()
    if (len(saleslist) > 0):
        query = "SELECT Trans_id, invoice, Product_id, Quantity, strftime('%m-%Y', Date) as month, Time " \
                "FROM sales WHERE strftime('%m',Date)='" + my_dictionary[tracing.get()] + "'"
        r_set = my_conn.execute(query)
        saleslist = r_set.fetchall()
        for i in range(0, len(saleslist)):
            saleslist[i] = list(saleslist[i])
            r_set.execute("select product_desc, units, product_price from products where product_id=?",
                      (int(saleslist[i][2]),))
            l = r_set.fetchall()
            saleslist[i] = [saleslist[i][0], saleslist[i][1], saleslist[i][2], l[0][0], saleslist[i][3], l[0][1],
                            l[0][2] * (int(saleslist[i][3])), saleslist[i][4],
                            saleslist[i][5]]
            saleslist[i] = tuple(saleslist[i])
        total = 0  # to store total sale of the selected date
        for dt in saleslist:
            trv.insert("", 'end', iid=dt[0], text=dt[0],
                       values=(dt[0], dt[1], dt[2], dt[3], dt[4], dt[5], dt[6], dt[7]))
            total = round(total + (dt[6]), 2)
        l2.config(text="Total: " + str(total) + "ssp")  # show total value
months = [r for r in my_dictionary.keys()]  # Month names as options

cb1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=months, width=10, textvariable= tracing)
cb1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=20,sticky='w')

r1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=year2, variable=r1_v, value=year2)
r1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='w')

r2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=year, variable=r1_v, value=year)
r2.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=10,sticky='w')

r3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=year1, variable=r1_v, value=year1)
r3.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=10,sticky='w')

scrollbary = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
trv = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("Transaction ID","Invoice No.", "Product ID", "Description",
                                                            "Quantity", "Units", "Price", "Month"), selectmode="browse", height=22,
                                 yscrollcommand=scrollbary.set)
trv.column('#0', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=0)
trv.column('#1', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
trv.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
trv.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=140)
trv.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=160)
trv.column('#5', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
trv.column('#6', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
trv.column('#7', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
trv.column('#8', stretch=NO, minwidth=0, width=120)
trv.heading('Transaction ID', text="Transaction ID", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Invoice No.', text="Invoice No.", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Product ID', text="Product ID", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Description', text="Description", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Quantity', text="Quantity", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Units', text="Units", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Price', text="Price", anchor=W)
trv.heading('Month', text="Month", anchor=W)
trv.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
scrollbary.config(command=trv.yview)
scrollbary.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ns", pady=10)
tracing.trace('w', my_function)
r1_v.trace('w', my_function)
l2 = tk.Label(root, font=('Times', 22, 'bold'), bg = "#63B8FF", fg = "red")
l2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='ne', pady=0)
root.mainloop()  # Keep the window open
```

*Below is the error message when i select the next year (2023)*

```
"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" E:/Sales-and-Inventory-Management-System-master/practice/image1.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/Sales-and-Inventory-Management-System-master/practice/image1.py", line 48, in my_function
    values=(dt[0], dt[1], dt[2], dt[3], dt[4], dt[5], dt[6], dt[7]))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1368, in insert
    "-id", iid, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: Item 105 already exists
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with radiobuttons. The error is coming from inserting something with a non-unique id into a treeview.

Comment: Someone please, help and correct that error.